# This map destructuring isn't working quite how I'd expect. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: clojure

As an example that, hopefully, states things far better than I could in words:

```
(let [{:keys [a b c] :or {a 1 b 2 c 3} :as m} {}]
  (println a b c) ; => works as expected, output is: 1 2 3
  (println m) ; => this doesn't work, output is: {}
)
```

I expected the output of the second println to be the map containing the default values as though shoved in there by merge (that is {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}).

Instead it looks like vars are being conjured and or'd after m is bound. Why does :as not get affected by :or like :keys does?

What's wrong with my mental model? How should I be looking at this?

**EDIT:**
I figured out how it works as I thought I'd shown above (although thanks for the links nonetheless). I've also since read through the source of clojure.core/destructure and now know exactly what it is doing. My question really is 'Why?'

In Clojure there always seems to be a reason things work the way they do. What are they here?

I apologize that the question came across as 'how does destructuring work with :as and :or'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not Rich, so obviously I didn't choose how this works, but I can think of a couple reasons the current behavior is better than the behavior you expected.

1. It's faster. A lot of Clojure's low-level core features get used *all the time* in your program, and they are optimized more for speed than elegance, in order to get acceptable performance. Of course if this were a matter of correctness it'd be a different story, but here there are two reasonable-sounding ways for `:as` to behave, so picking the faster one seems like a good plan. As for why it's faster, I presume this is obvious, but: we already have a pointer to the original map, which we can just reuse. To use the "modified" map, we have to build it with a bunch of assoc calls.
2. If `:as` doesn't give you back the original object, how can you possibly get the original object? You can't, really, right? Whereas if `:as` gives you back the original object, you can easily construct a modified version if you want. So one behavior leaves more options open to you.

Comment: Ah! that second point had escaped me completely. In retrospect, it should not have. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Special Forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms), `:as` and `:or` are both on their own in regards to the `init-expr`:

> In addition, and optionally, an `:as` key in the binding form followed by a symbol will cause that symbol **to be bound to the entire init-expr**. Also optionally, an `:or` key in the binding form followed **by another map** may be used to supply default values for some or all of the keys **if they are not found in the init-expr**

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, the `:or` key in the destructuring does not influence `:as`. `:as` will capture the original input, regardless of the application of defaults or encapsulation of remaining elements via `&` etc.

To quote [the docs on clojure.org](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring))

> Also optionally, an :or key in the binding form followed by another
>   map may be used to supply default values for some or all of the keys
>   if they are not found in the init-expr

...

> Finally, also optional, :as followed by a symbol will cause that
>   symbol to be bound to the entire init-expr